# How do I convert a simple command parser maven project into a dropwizard project

Tags: java, maven, command-line, dropwizard

I have been struggling with converting a simple maven into a dropwizard project, but what I came up with is only failure, so I am asking you help.

My original purpose of the project was to parse options passed as command arguments, for example `java -jar target/myJar.jar -u username -p password -d database -h hostname -f file_or_directory -rec`. Now I want to change this into a dropwizard project, to add some more functionalities that goes along with my main purpose.

My research suggested to use dropwizard's [command](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/core.html#man-core-commands), but this is not working for me. I tried, but every time I do `java -jar target/myJar.jar hello -u world`, I get

```
invalid choice: 'hello' (choose from 'server', 'check')
usage: java -jar myJar.jar
   [-h] [-v] {server,check} ...

positional arguments:
  {server,check}         available commands

optional arguments:
  -h, --help             show this help message and exit
  -v, --version          show the application version and exit
```

While there are a lot of questions on this subject, I haven't been able to find a solution that worked for me, and I would appreciate your input.

And while I am on a dropwizard project, any idea why I can't access my app at `localhost:8080`? The app is running, but every time I try to access it there I get error code `404`.

Comment: In your application class: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldApplication.java#L64 and the Command itself: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/cli/RenderCommand.java#L15-L48

Comment: I had put the that in `run()` instead of `initialize()`! I spend a whole day re-reading my code, but I couldn't find that mistake.